# engineering notation literal "3e-3" turning into numbers in J

Tags: j

I read a csv file in J, which has numbers in engineering notation, such as 3e-3.

In J, I can turn a literal into number by `".`

```
". '3e3'
3000
```

and

```
". '3e_3'
0.003
```

But how to turn '3e-3' into 0.003

```
". '3e-3'
ill-formed number
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either guide `".` by forcing it to evaluate to a number by giving it a default value:

```
0 ". '3e-3'
```

Or `charsub` the offending character:

```
'-_' charsub ". '3e-3'
```

I'd recommend the first, execution with `".` is potentially dangerous, so forcing it to interpret numbers when that's what's desired is best practice.

Comment: Thanks. I read the ". in J Dictionary again, it's in there: the last example, dyadic form.